# identify a transparent stem plant?

Tags: identification

I am from the south of mexico, and am not sure what is this, the stem looks like plastic, the pot had like 10 different seeds before, or maybe is just a weird weed I have to cut?

[image: it looks like plastic too]

[image: and have a red part too]

Comment: If it is a weed, you should look nearby you, and try to see similar leaves. To me, it seems a Lamiaceae (Labiatae): some are weeds, some aromatic plants: could you rub some leaves and smell it? [My bets are on mint]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say 'the pot had, like, 10 different seeds before'? It seems to  suggest you planted 10 different individual seeds of various  plants in the pot, is that what you mean?

Comment: sorry, it doesnt have any smell, and to Bamboo, yeah, pretty much that, I planted 10 different things hoping at least 1 would born, im bad with plants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "**Pilea pumila**" commonly known as **clearweed**. It is a member of the nettle family (**Urticaceae**) and has a broad native range in North America. It is usually thought of as a weed, but apparently Native Americans once used in for medicinal purposes. There are many links online about it. Here are two of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilea_pumila

https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/pilea/pumila/